# MySQL transaction and buffered list of requests

Tags: c++, mysql, libmysql

I have a C++ code that parses files and updates the MySQL Database according to the content of these files.
I run my code in Windows 10, with MySQL 5.7, and my base uses the InnoDB engine. The MySQL calls are performed through a wrapper of my own around libmysql.

In an attempt to optimize this code, I append the update requests in a buffer until reaching the maximum size of the buffer, then send the whole buffer (containing N updates) at the same time. This whole process is done inside a single transaction.

Here is how my code looks:

```
MySQLWrapper.StartTransaction();

string QueryBuffer = "";

// Element count is the number of elements parsed from the files
for( int i = 0 ; i < ElementCount ; ++i )
{
bool FlushBuffer = 
( i> 0 && ! (( i + 1 ) % N) )    ||
( i == ElementCount - 1 ); // determines if we have reached the buffer max number of requests

QueryBuffer += "INSERT INTO mytable (myfield) VALUES (" Element[ i ] ");";

if( FlushBuffer )
{
MySQLWrapper.SendRequest( QueryBuffer );
QueryBuffer.assign("");
}
}
MySQLWrapper.Commit();
```

The implementation of SendRequest(string Request ) would basically be:

```
void SendRequest(string Request)
{
mysql_query( SQLSocket, Request.c_str())
}
```

However, when committing the transaction, the transaction happens to have been broken: MySQL indicates that that the state is incorrect for comitting. I have tried to do the same thing but sending requests ony by one, and this error does not happen at the moment of the commit.

So, my 2 questions are:

1. Do you know why the fact to send multiple requests at a time breaks my transaction?
2. Do you think that the use of a buffered list of requests can really optimize my code?

Comment: Instead of multiple INSERTs, create one INSERT with multiple values. IOW, before the loop, have the ```INSERT INTO TABLE (columns)```, then inside the loop, append ```(values),``` for each value set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of multiple INSERTs, create one INSERT with multiple values. IOW, before the loop, 
have the `INSERT INTO TABLE (columns)`, then inside the loop, append `(values),` for each value set.

```
MySQLWrapper.StartTransaction();

string QueryBuffer = "INSERT INTO mytable (myfield) VALUES ";

// Element count is the number of elements parsed from the files
for( int i = 0 ; i < ElementCount ; ++i )
{
    bool FlushBuffer = 
    ( i> 0 && ! (( i + 1 ) % N) )    ||
    ( i == ElementCount - 1 ); // determines if we have reached the buffer max number of requests

    QueryBuffer += "(" Element[ i ] ")";
    if( flushbuffer ) {
        QueryBuffer += ";";
    } else {
        QueryBuffer += ",";
    }

    if( FlushBuffer )
    {
        MySQLWrapper.SendRequest( QueryBuffer );
        QueryBuffer.assign("");
    }
}
MySQLWrapper.Commit();
```

The resulting SQL statement will be something like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
(myfield)
VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(3);
```